# Eliminate Authentication process in share point 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

I want to eliminate the Windows Authentication and FBA Authentication completely, and want to incorporate my own authentication process.

How'd i do that. I want to create a public facing website in sharepoint.

Any help or way points will be highly appreciated.

Thanx.

Comment: If it is a public facing website, do you need any kind of authentication at all? Can you post more information about the authentication process you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to use it for a public website you can allow anonymous access you don't have to add a custom authentication process.

But.. to enable a custom sql authentication provider take a look at these articles

http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2010/05/07/configuring-claims-and-forms-based-authentication-for-use-with-a.aspx

http://www.sunilyadav.net/2010/12/implement-multiple-authentication-providers-in-sharepoint-2010/

Another point for public SharePoint sites is licensing as you may need the Internet Site license for 2010.

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/licensing-details.aspx